# Store data on element before appending

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to store JSON on an html element using jquery `data()`. However my elements are actually an html string and are not yet in the DOM like so.

```
$(".test").each(function() {
  el += "<span>"+ 25 +"</span>";
});

$("body").append(el);
```

I have tried this (within each function)

```
el += $("<span>"+ 25 +"</span>").data("test", {"name":"john"});
```

But when I append `el`, I get `[object][object]` appended instead

How can I associate the data with the element and be able to retrieve it after its appended?

FIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/6mhgwtk1/1/

Comment: Are you alerting the value, instead use console logging

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did it right, but it's an object. When you print or alert an object it will always appear as `[Object]`. Instead  of printing the object print it's properties instead, like this: `el.data("test").name`.

see: https://jsfiddle.net/6mhgwtk1/

---

Based on your example code, I've updated your fiddle with working code. See the comments for the explanation.. https://jsfiddle.net/6mhgwtk1/3/

```
var el;
$("div").each(function() {
   // el is not a string here, (it's a jQuery object) so you can't concatentate it using +=
   // instead you will have to append each one to the body separately
    el = $("<span>"+ 25 +"</span>").data("test", {"name":"john"});
  $("body").append(el);
});


$("body").find("span").each(function(){
   var data = $(this).data("test");
   console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: I don't want to use its properties yet. I want to append the span element and then use the json data elsewhere in my script

Comment: @guub If you didn't understand my answer you will have to post the code that is using the object so I can give a more relevant example. The object is in `el.data("test")`. You got that already, the problem is how you're using it and you didn't post that code. If you need further help you will have to post your code.

Comment: @guub - Please see my update, if you have questions please ask, if I answered your question, please hit the checkmark by my answer. Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

For retrieving, Try getting attributes of el (since it is an object).